# Refine mesh obtained with CGAL::Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction

Tags: cgal

I reconstruct a 3D surface mesh using the advancing front surface reconstruction and would like to refine it. How can I achieve this?

This is part of the code used for surface reconstruction with refinement by passing through a file:

```
#include <CGAL/Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction.h>
#include <CGAL/compute_average_spacing.h>

#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_data_structure_3.h>

#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/Polyhedron_iostream.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/refine.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/fair.h>

typedef CGAL::Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction<> Reconstruction;
typedef Reconstruction::Triangulation_3 Triangulation_3;
typedef Reconstruction::Triangulation_data_structure_2 TDS_2;
typedef Reconstruction::Outlier_range Outlier_range;
typedef Reconstruction::Boundary_range Boundary_range;
typedef Reconstruction::Vertex_on_boundary_range Vertex_on_boundary_range;
typedef Reconstruction::Vertex_handle Vertex_handle;

typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<CGALMesher::Kernel> Polyhedron;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<CGALMesher::Point> Mesh;
typedef CGAL::cpp11::array<std::size_t,3> Facet;

struct Construct {
        Mesh& mesh;
        template<typename PointIterator>
        Construct(Mesh& mesh, PointIterator b, PointIterator e) : mesh(mesh) {
                for (; b != e; ++b) {
                        boost::graph_traits<Mesh>::vertex_descriptor v;
                        v = add_vertex(mesh);
                        mesh.point(v) = *b;
                }
        }
        Construct& operator=(const Facet f) {
                typedef boost::graph_traits<Mesh>::vertex_descriptor vertex_descriptor;
                typedef boost::graph_traits<Mesh>::vertices_size_type size_type;
                mesh.add_face(vertex_descriptor(static_cast<size_type>(f[0])),
                                vertex_descriptor(static_cast<size_type>(f[1])),
                                vertex_descriptor(static_cast<size_type>(f[2])));
                return *this;
        }
        Construct&
        operator*() {
                return *this;
        }
        Construct&
        operator++() {
                return *this;
        }
        Construct operator++(int) {
                return *this;
        }
};

void CGALMesher::AdvancingFrontMesher(std::vector<Point>& points) {

        Mesh m;
        Construct construct(m,points.begin(),points.end());

        CGAL::advancing_front_surface_reconstruction(points.begin(), points.end(), construct);

        std::ofstream mesh_off("mesh.off");
        mesh_off << m;
        mesh_off.close();

        std::ifstream input("mesh.off");
        Polyhedron poly;
        if ( !input || !(input >> poly) || poly.empty() ) {
                std::cerr << "Not a valid off file." << std::endl;
        }
        input.close();

        std::vector<Polyhedron::Facet_handle>  new_facets;
        std::vector<Polyhedron::Vertex_handle> new_vertices;

        CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::refine(poly,
                                  faces(poly),
                                  std::back_inserter(new_facets),
                                  std::back_inserter(new_vertices),
                                  CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::parameters::density_control_factor(3));

        std::ofstream refined_off("refined.off");
        refined_off << poly;
        refined_off.close();
        std::cout << "Refinement added " << new_vertices.size() << " vertices." << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you extracted a polyhedral surface out of the reconstruction algorithm, you can use the [`refine()`](http://doc.cgal.org/4.7/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PkgPolygonMeshProcessing.html#ga159ff517d211ec30f3fdb799a24834a8) function from the polygon mesh processing package. There is also the possibility to use the [`fair()`](http://doc.cgal.org/4.7/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PkgPolygonMeshProcessing.html#gace913be23db0481afc1fea6c6bdfb250).

More drastically, you can use remeshing algorithm like this [one](http://doc.cgal.org/4.7/Surface_mesher/index.html#Chapter_3D_Surface_Mesh_Generation). In CGAL 4.8, there will also be the function `isotropic_remeshing()` that is already available in the master [branch](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal).

Comment: I posted part of the code for surface reconstruction above. As far as I understand, I have to convert the triangulation obtained from the reconstruction to a 2D complex in 3D Delaunay triangulation before doing a polyhedral surface. However I don't understand how to achieve this.

Comment: Checkout [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CGAL/cgal/master/Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction/examples/Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction/reconstruction_surface_mesh.cpp) example.

Comment: I edited the code above, now it works. However I pass the mesh through a file. Is there any way to avoid this and go directly to refinement?

Comment: Simply call refine on `m`

Comment: You mean: CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::refine(m, ...)? There must be a cast of types.

Comment: Yes, `refine` can be applied on any model of [`MutableFaceGraph`](http://doc.cgal.org/4.7/BGL/classMutableFaceGraph.html) and `Surface_mesh` is a model.